# How to deploy Opportunity Stage picklist using Apache ANT Tool?

Tags: metadata, ant

How can I deploy the Opportunity Stage picklist of my Sandbox to production?
I've retrieved it with ANT but can't deploy it...

I've retrieved from the sandbox, changed some text in the description and deploy to the same sandbox, expecting to see the change, but nothing happens... No error message...

Thanks!

package.xml section

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>OpportunityStage</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

OportunityStage.standardValueSet section

```
<standardValue>
    <fullName>StageTest1</fullName>
    <default>false</default>
    <description>Stage Test 1</description>
    <label>StageTest1</label>
    <closed>false</closed>
    <forecastCategory>Pipeline</forecastCategory>
    <probability>10</probability>
    <won>false</won>
</standardValue>
```

Comment: What API version are you using in the deployment?

Comment: Hi David! 
I'm using 48

Comment: Sounds good. Could you [edit] your post to describe the failure mode in more detail? Include any errors verbatim and describe what happens when you perform the deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that nothing happens!
I use to deploy classes, triggers, Profiles... but nothing happens when I deploy th OpportunityStage. No errors.. but nothing changes

Comment: 1) StandardValueSet doesn't support wildcard (*) in package.xml

Comment: Can you edit 'StageTest1' lov on stage field and check if you see any description?  I tried with below and it worked.    <StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Test3</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
  <description>Stage Test 1</description>
        <label>Test3</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
        <forecastCategory>Pipeline</forecastCategory>
        <probability>80</probability>
        <won>false</won>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>

Comment: Thank cropredy.... that was the quiz!
Thank you very much to all of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[StandardValueSet doesn't support the wildcard (*) in package.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm?search_text=standardvalueset). Remove that line and simply use:

```
<types>
    <members>OpportunityStage</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

Note also when adding/changing/deleting `StageName`, you should also deploy `BusinessProcess`

Comment: When deploying this I got: `ComponentSetError: No source-backed components present in the package.` This was caused by a `/**` at the bottom of my `.forceignore`.